# how to pass in a class name as variable using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I pass in a class name as a variable using javascript?

Let's say I have the class Person.

I want to pass in the name of the class to a function so that that function can call that class.

so the function is

```
function openClass(name)
```

I want to pass in

```
openClass('person')
```

so that openClass can call the class person

for example

```
function openClass(name)
{
    return new name() // here I want this line to actually 
                      // call the class "Person" if that is 
                      // what is passed in as a name parameter,

}
```

Comment: since classes are just functions, this is a duplicate of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, there are no classes in JavaScript. Although many third party libraries do create a class system on top of JavaScript.

The "class" is typically a constructor function. So if you have the name of the function, it's  a matter of digging it out of the global scope. Assuming the function is defined globally:

```
var Constructor = window[name];
return new Constructor();
```

If your function is actually defined at say `my.namespace.Person`, then it's a bit more complicated, but still the same general idea.

Comment: Also assuming `window` is the global object. It isn't always (say in node.js for example)

Comment: People seem to be downvoting this approach (see dystroy's answer too), curious why

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
function openClass(name) {
    return new window[name]();
}
```

[Demonstration](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/newPerson.html) (open the console)

Of course, if you don't declare your class as a global function but in a specific object or array, just replace window by this object or array.

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass the constructor of that class.  So if the class is Person, it will have a constructor

```
var Person = function(){
    //...
}

you can pass that in to getClass as an argument

var getClass = function(constructor){
    return new constructor()
};

var newObject = getClass(Person);
```

Answer (score -3):

Simply call `openClass(Person)`.

That passes the `Person` function into `openClass`, where it can be called normally.

If you really *need* to pass it as a string, then you can look for the `Person` function by name:

```
window[name]
```

Comment: Oh, that's curious, all the responses had one downvote except this one...you need to do that with 12.7k reputation?